# Webpack/Vue Build intermittently results in broken reference

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm seeing an intermittent issue with Webpack building a Vue app.

Every few builds, we see this error when opening the site:

```
Unknown custom element: <MyButton> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Comparing the compiled code in the 'broken' code to 'working' code, the only difference I see is that in the working code we have:

`file="src/components/MyButton.vue";t.a=i.exports}`

In the 'broken' code, that `t.a=` part is missing:

`file="src/components/MyButton.vue";i.exports}`

I'm at a loss here. What's going on?

Comment: this error msg comes when your not importing `MyButton` on the parent component. maybe check the `import Mybutton....` line.

Comment: Yep, everything is fine. As I said, the pain here is that the issue is intermittent. If I run the build 5 times, this error will appear one or two times.

Comment: looks like cache issue.... have you tried clearing it?

Comment: What cache? Seems to me like this is a webpack error?

Comment: i mean, does it happen when you clear your cache? (ctrl+shift+i -->network-> disable cache, or running on incognito)

Comment: Have you discovered the fix for this? I'm seeing the same thing.